# Azure Active Directory - Mining oAuth2Permission, appRole and group claims from JWT token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Scenario: I have 2 AAD applications in different Azure tenants - lets call Tenant A and B. The app in tenant A defines custom appRole and oAuth2Permissions that have been consented to by app in Tenant B. The app in Tenant B defines a KeyCredential using its own cert.

I am able to get a JWT token successfully using ADAL v3 passing in the
ClientAssertionCertificate (resource is the app in Tenant A and client is the app in Tenant B) like so:

```
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        X509Certificate2 cert = AuthHelper.FindCertificateByThumbprint("<Thumbprint of the Tenant B app's KeyCredential cert>");
        ClientAssertionCertificate assertionCert = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, assertionCert).Result;
        string accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken; // Valid.
        string idToken = authenticationResult.IdToken; // Null.
```

The AuthenticationResult from AcquireTokenAsync contains the AccessToken that I can validate successfully as well...

```
        string issuer = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantid"]);
        string audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["audience"];
        string certThumbprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certThumbprint"];
        var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Concat(issuer, URI_DELIMITER, STS_DISCOVERY_ENDPOINT_SUFFIX);

        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);
        var config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        // extract issuer and token for validation
        var authority = config.Issuer;
        var signingTokens = config.SigningTokens.ToList();

        sys.TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new sys.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            ValidAudience = audience,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningTokens = signingTokens,
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,                
        };

        sys.JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new sys.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        sys.SecurityToken jwt;
        var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
```

1. The IdToken is however empty. Is this because I have no UserAssertion passed in to the AcquireTokenAsync call?
2. To be able to further Authorize the request, I'm looking for - appRole, oAuth2Permissions and groupMembership claims. These claims are however not in the AccessToken. If this is expected, then when do I find the said claims in the token. If this is not expected, what am I missing in the token generation or AAD app setup that would cause this?

NOTE: My scenario does not involve Web APIs (but it is WAAD bound) so I'd have to do the token validation and authorization manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. ID token is only generated if you follow authentication flows involving a user.
   At no point in your authentication do you sign the user in, so I cannot understand what kind of ID Token you would expect to get...

   You need to follow the Authorization Code Grant flow to sign in a user, and get a delegated token.
2. I have [a blog post](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/clients-tokens-claims-oh-my/) on how to get groupMembership claims to appear between two applications.

   There is no such think as an "oAuth2Permission" claim in an access token. You can find all the different tokens and claims supported by AAD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims).

   Ultimately, you should be relying on the AAD Graph API to get these details, not the token, because the token has intrinsic size limits which may leave out data about certain roles or groups which exist.

Comment: Hey Shawn, 1). I am trying to implement the Authorization Code grant flow and hence no user-sign is expected. My app exposes only "Admin" roles and scopes. These have been consented by the client tenant admin and I can see these roles & scopes for the resource in my client app. 2) In the article you pointed to, it clearly states that the claims - "roles", "scope" and "groups" are present in Id_Tokens and i can confirm this because I don't see these in the Access token. Does this mean these don't flow in JWT AccessToken? How do I extract these claims then?

Comment: Authorization Code Grant flow is exactly the flow where user sign-in is expected. See [this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/media/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/active-directory-oauth-code-flow-native-app.png). The claims should be in the access token you receive. You should share the access token if you believe the scopes are not there.

Comment: Here's a sample access token I'd generated earlier..     {
  "aud": "eabeb052-4b2b-444e-a026-1ff7a6a84368",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantid>/",
  "iat": 1507849727,
  "nbf": 1507849727,
  "exp": 1507853627,
  "aio": "Y2VgYJjx43f+7Zak9czdS24+vZulDQA=",
  "appid": "342db626-3683-4de3-a5a4-d37833a60c39",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenantid>/",
  "oid": "8210e749-83b9-42fb-ad16-6383a5259ba2",
  "sub": "8210e749-83b9-42fb-ad16-6383a5259ba2",
  "tid": "6074560d-0ce2-43ab-b7f4-9fe26a09b022",
  "ver": "1.0"
}

Comment: The point I was trying to make earlier is that in my scenario, there are no "user scopes" and the "admin" scopes have already been consented to - manually by the client  tenant's admin. That said, what is not evident is "how" one gets the Authorization Code using ADAL. If I understand right all AcquireToken* APIs are for obtaining the token once the authorization code is generated.

Comment: That token has the claim `"appidacr":"2"` which is authentication by certificate. The rest of the token implies that you are doing a [Service to Service call](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) which is the flow that does NOT trigger an authorization code. Your token shows me that you have not established Application Permissions between your client and resource. You should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes#app-only-vs-delegated-scopes)

Comment: In my scenario, the resource defines the following: "appRoles": [   {  "allowedMemberTypes":  "Application" ], "displayName": "Collaborator", "id": "a0ee5d40-329e-4824-9ed1-40ed44e44e9e", "isEnabled": true, "description": "Blah...", "value": "Collaborator" }  ], ....
"oauth2Permissions": [ { "adminConsentDescription": "Allow reading all objs my application", "adminConsentDisplayName": "View objs on my application", "id": "b452883c-55e4-4d4a-be1b-6f9884571858",  "isEnabled": true, "type": "Admin", "value": "Read.All"  },...

Comment: .... and my client app has consented to these thus having these resourceAccess entries (as seen in manifest): "resourceAppId": "eabeb052-4b2b-444e-a026-1ff7a6a84368",
      "resourceAccess": [  {
          "id": "a0ee5d40-329e-4824-9ed1-40ed44e44e9e",
          "type": "Role"
        },
        {
          "id": "b452883c-55e4-4d4a-be1b-6f9884571858",
          "type": "Scope"
        }       
      ]
    }.. and my understanding is when this client requests a token against that resource access scope/role claims will be present.